# Combining stack exchange accounts with different emails

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have an account with tex.stackexchange.com and math.stackexchange.com that use different email accounts. I want to combine these. I have changed the email accounts so they match, but the accounts are still treated as different. Ideas?

Comment: If you add the same OpenId to both accounts (not an email, but a login method, under "add logins..."), the system ought to merge you. But contacting SE, as Mooseman said, works too.

Comment: That works.  Adding the OpenId and then deleting other logins (this may not be necessary) and logging out and then back in has combined all the accounts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to [contact Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) to merge your accounts.

Comment: Thank you, will contact now